Visual studio 2022 components that install media foundation lib files
I have a DLL program with the following heading codes for Visual Studio 2022 professional edition.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "mf.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfidl.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat.lib")


The problems I am getting is "LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfapi.lib'" link errors. mf___.lib files are not installed in my VS. How can I install Windows Media Foundation lib files for VS 2022? Which components should I install to get those lib files? Include files are already in the paths. Only lib files are missing.
First I tried with community edition with "Build ALL". Then profession edition. I checked lib directories. mf__.lib files are missing in lib folders.

There's a MFC component in the installer, have you installed that?

For unknown reasons, VS is installing but if I check again, MFC is unchecked again. I tried many times both professional and community version. I am not sure why VC is not installing properly.

This is probably a question to ask at the Microsoft Forums. With that said I believe the VS Installer logs actions so you may have some information available to help  understand the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69271672/visual-studio-installation-logs-location-2019

I think Media Foundation is deplicated.

There is no  mfapi.lib and  mfidl.lib.
Use
#include <windows.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "mf.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Mfreadwrite.lib")


You are right. I was using ChatGPT generated sample code snippets. It's full of wrong codes.  The lib I need is mfuuid.lib. I found out by trying all available lib files!
